# How to understand this sentence? "If the sequence of letters lexicographically precedes the first word on the page, we know to go backwards."

Tags: sentence-meaning

> If the sequence of letters lexicographically precedes the first word on the page, we know to **go backwards**.

Why is it go backwards? I think it should be go forward. How to understand this sentence?

I got this sentence from a python textbook (Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python). The whole paragraph is as follows:

> Fortunately, the folks who publish hard-copy dictionaries go to the trouble of putting the words in lexicographical order. This allows us to open the book to a page where we think the word might lie (e.g., near the middle for words starting with the letter m). **If the sequence of letters lexicographically precedes the first word on the page, we know to go backwards.** If the sequence of letters follows the last word on the page, we know to go forwards. Otherwise, we check whether the sequence of letters matches a word on the page.

Comment: Please include the source where you found the sentence and some context.  It looks like you found this at https://venali.medium.com/unconventional-intro-to-python-numerical-programs-iii-ae5a722148c3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence looks correct as it is.  The author is talking about looking up a sequence of letters in a dictionary.

We can break it down like this:

If the sequence of letters *(that we are looking for)*
lexicographically *(in dictionary order)*
precedes *(comes before)*
the first word on the page, *(of the dictionary that we are looking at)*
we know to go backwards. *(in the dictionary)*

So for example, if our sequence of letters is **DESTITUTE**, but the first word on the dictionary page that we are looking at is **DIBBLE**,
we would go *backwards* in the dictionary (to an *earlier* page) because DESTITUTE comes *before* DIBBLE in dictionary order.

Comment: One wonders why they don't just say alphabetically....

Comment: @Lambie - that's Pythonistas for you. One reason I prefer Ruby as a language.